# Split the string to string array then split the array to hashmap in java or groovy

Tags: java, arrays, string, groovy

I have string like below

SUB_SYSTEM_ERROR@!@Error Getting from sub system@$@Record already Exists@!@Record Already Exists

First I have to split the string with @$@. hten Array will be like

SUB_SYSTEM_ERROR@!@Error Getting from sub system, Record already Exists@!@Record Already Exists

Then I have split the array with @!@ and make to hashmap like below.

(SUB_SYSTEM_ERROR, Error Getting from sub system)
(Record already Exists, Record Already Exists)

Please help on this either in groovy or java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
x.split('@\\$@').collect { it.split('@!@') as List }​.collectEntries()​
```

where `x` is your input string

Comment: It shows compilation error. ':' ,'}' or new line has to be added.

Comment: it does work in groovyConsole http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5733170917933056

Comment: It is a bug with idea. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-89897

Thanks bro